# Eclipse Plugin: Opening dialogs alongside quickfix

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I'm working on a plugin and am trying to add some additional information around the quickfix menu that is triggered by clicking on my custom markers.

I'm adding a method call in MarkerResolutionGenerator.getResolutions() to draw the new dialog window, but I'm having trouble getting it to agree with the quickfix dialog. I can get it to draw at the same time, but I can't control the position and it also draws an extra blank dialog in the background.

Any thoughts? Relevant code below. The first two methods are from my MarkerResolutionGenerator, and my custom class is below that. (I just copied it from an example, I'm more worried about getting it to behave before I work on the content.)

```
@Override
public IMarkerResolution[] getResolutions(IMarker marker) 
{
    IMarker problem = marker;

    makeStuff();
    ...
}

private void makeStuff()
{
    Display display = Activator.getDefault().getWorkbench().getDisplay();
    Shell shell = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor()
            .getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getShell();

    Shell myShell = new Shell(shell, SWT.NO_TRIM);

    MyDialog md = new MyDialog(myShell);
    md.open();
}


public class MyDialog extends Dialog
{
    public MyDialog(Shell parentShell) 
    {
        super(parentShell);
        setShellStyle(SWT.CLOSE | SWT.MODELESS | SWT.BORDER | SWT.TITLE);
        setBlockOnOpen(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) 
    {
        Composite container = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
        Button button = new Button(container, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.CENTER, false, false));
        button.setText("Press me");
        button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Pressed");
            }
        });

        return container;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: `Dialog` creates its own shell so your `myShell` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to create another `Shell`? Why not just use the one you already have as parent for your dialog? It might be the reason for the "extra blank dialog in the background".

You should be able to set the initial position overriding `getInitialLocation` in your custom dialog:

```
@Override
protected Point getInitialLocation(Point initialSize) {
    return new Point(10, 10);  // x and y coordinates of the initial position
}
```

Comment: That gets me pretty close, but the reason why I thought I needed an additional shell was because if I use the active shell, the quickfix dialog doesn't remain visible. It blinks quickly, then goes away and leaves the custom dialog.

Comment: If you open myShell with `myShell.open()` you will have the extra blank dialog, so make sure you are not doing that. If you are still having trouble try to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce the problem

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've pulled out myShell but I now have the issue that I described above. I can try to make a MCVE, but I would have to get permission from someone that I'm collaborating with to post their code. Hopefully the code I posted makes sense, since the immediate caller is an internal class.

Comment: You don't have to use your actual code, just something that show the problem

Comment: So I think the issue is that the new dialog is taking focus, which makes the quickfix dialog die. I can tell this is the issue because the quickfix will come up if I quickly tab back to the editor between the jface dialog and quickfix dialog loading. Is there anyway to make the jface dialog not take focus when opening?